# TomCat automatic closing.JVM Fatal Error in native code, Not sure what to do

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, ehcache

I'm using Apache Tomcat 8.5.4 Server. Hibernate 4.3 with EhCache. JSF with Primefaces 5.2.JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Is generating this crash report:

```
2017-04-24 07:43:51 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000016d2514, pid=1644, tid=0x0000000000000e88
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# j  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getClassMapping(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/mapping/PersistentClass;+5
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# Can not save log file, dump to screen..
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000016d2514, pid=1644, tid=0x0000000000000e88
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# j  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getClassMapping(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/mapping/PersistentClass;+5
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
```

Comment: It seems to be a known problem, after a quick Google search I found this:
 https://www.java.com/en/download/help/exception_access.xml

Comment: My uac was already disabled